# aws sdk c++ async http request?

Tags: c++, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-cpp

Using AWS C++ SDK, how can I make an asynchronous http request and get my callback executed with the response?

There is

```
Aws::Http::HttpClient::MakeRequest
```

but its synchronous.

Comment: Did you have a look at `std::async`?

Comment: @sebrockm yep, I implemented it with `std::async`, but was wondering if there is any _AWS SDK native_ way to do this - like, there are various async functions such as `Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::CognitoIdentityProviderClient::AdminEnableUserAsync`